# How to hide back button on ios with wix react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I have been stuck on this problem all morning. I have read multiple GitHub issues and StackOverflow posts and nothing has worked.

I want to remove the blue back button in the top left of the below pic.
[image]
I have noticed I am having trouble customizing the top bar altogether. I cannot add a title to the back button etc (this hint might indicate what is wrong).

Navigation.setRoot

```
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Reactotron.log('5');
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      stack: {
        children: [{
          component: {
            id: STARTING_SCREEN,
            name: STARTING_SCREEN
          }
        }],
      }
    },
    layout: {
      orientation: 'portrait',
    },
  }).then(()=>Reactotron.log('7'));
```

Navigation.push

SplashScreen (root screen) -> AccessScreen (next screen).

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: screen
  },
  options: {
    topBar: {
      backButton: {
        visible: false,
      }
    }
  }
```

It's almost as if I am specifying the backButton options in the wrong place.

Comment: you can try use `headerMode: "none"`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. I don't understand why headerMode: "none" would help? Where would you put it?

Comment: It shall be placed in the 'StackNavigator'.Because the Backward button is also in the header.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky workaround

```
 leftButtons: [
      {
        id: 'something',
        text: '',
      },
    ],
```

the `text: ''` will keep a empty space, so will hide the button.

Actually not hide, but yea you can say that too.

You're good to go!!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: I updated the Navigation.push to contain your above code and it didn't work*. Is it meant to be in the Navigation.setRoot?

Answer (score 0):

Use it but only working for ios

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
    topBar: {
      backButton: {
        visible: false
      }
    },
})
```

or you can customize topBar

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: screen
  },
  options: {
    topBar: {
      backButton: {
        background: YourComponent
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Note my version react-native-navigation v3 but i ithink it works for v2 too